# What was happening with Dr. Lou?

Tags: project-almanac

In [*Project Almanac*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2436386/), after David tries to "fix" something he returns to find things drastically changed.  One of those things, which seemed curious to me, was Dr. Lou walking through the lobby carrying a box of what appeared to be his personal belongings, and David asks him where he is going, to which Dr. Lou replies (or something simliar to):

> No need to be such a smartass, Mr. Raskin.

I took this to mean that something David did caused Dr. Lou to get fired.  The group was able to trace all of the other differences to a couple specific events, and we see them do this.  But is there any information as to what happened to Dr. Lou?

Comment: +1 just because it's not "star-wars" :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the whole point was that there were a ton of differences in the timeline that the characters couldn't explain: having more followers on Instagram, being part of the "cool" clique, etc.

The characters can't track down the cause and effect of everything that changed, and because we only really see what the characters see, neither do we.

Answer (score 1):

When David changes the past, more specifically, the events of Lollapalooza, it caused changes to other events and new events to happen. Like -

- David was surprised that his mom was going out for interviews.
- Sarah Nathan's brother got injured, hence couldn't play in the basketball game.
- Sarah Nathan was crying since her father who was the pilot, died in the plane crash.
- Forest fires.
- David asks Dr.Lou where he's going, to which Dr Lou replies -

  > Don't be a wiseass, David.

Now, obviously, David is surprised because he didn't expect Lou's reaction that way. But it's not mentioned any further why Dr Lou reacted that way to David. However, Adam and Quinn later explain it as a whole on why there are different changes to the current reality.

It's because of the ripple effects they caused when they visited Lollapalooza, and more so with David's little alone trip to the past so that he could be with Jessie. But David's not ready to accept this and undo their mistakes, since it would lead to him losing Jessie.

Other than this, there's no further mention on why Dr Lou reacted the way he did. Possibly, the new reality's David did something to him getting fired, or Lou's just annoyed with David for some reason.